# Why doesn't gcc report error for following duplicate symbols?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

I'm working on Ubuntu Linux to build Android and Linux binary. I have a static library which has been linked by two shared libraries, and there is a global object in the static library.

By my understanding, the global object will be exist in both `*.so`, and will cause issues because the function symbols in each shared library access different global variables.

(I referred the static library in the command line when building both shared libraries. I have been using `-Wl,--whole-archive` and `-Wl,-z,defs` switches. So the shared library contains the symbols of the static library.)

So the question is:

1. When linking the executable, why doesn't the GCC/LD report duplicate symbols error for this case?
2. Does that means we never link to the same static library in an application's shared library and the executable itself?

-----------------Edit 1-----------------------

As **R Soha** said we shouldn't have status in static library, or should provide an shared library.

And I think it is bad and sad to have this limitation: Static library should not have status or should be provide as an shared libraries.

The reason is:
 1. The global variable is common used, for example in my case, it is an singleton object. 
 2. The static library may be provided by an third party. And maybe the user also using an shared library provide by another third party, which has already linked the static library, for example boost.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a static library which has been linked by two shared libraries'?  Do you mean that you linked the program with two shared libraries and a static library?  Or that when you built the shared libraries, you referred to a static library in the command line that built each shared library?  In either case, it is (TTBOMK) unlikely that the shared library contains anything from the static library per se.

Comment: I means the later case. I referred the static library in command line when build both shared library. I have using `-Wl,--whole-archive` and `-Wl,-z,defs` switch. So the shared library contains the symbols of the static library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> By my understanding the global object will be exist in both *.so, and will cause issue because the function symbols in each shared library access different global variable.

That is correct. The global variable used by first .so will be different from the global variable used by the second .so.

As for your questions...

> When link the executable, Why the GCC/LD doesn't report duplicate symbols error for this case?

As far as the executable is concerned, it only cares about the interfaces of the .so libraries. It doesn't care about the fact that they have been created by using the same static library(ies).

> Does that means we never link to the same static library in an application's shared library and the executable itself?

It is OK if the static libraries don't have state. If they have state, you have to make a judgement call on whether the state needs to be global across the application or only in a shared library.

If the state needs to be global across the application, it will be better to create another shared library that provides access to the global state instead of putting it in a static library.

If the state needs to be maintained in each shared library, they putting it in the static library is OK. Even then, creating a shared library that provides access to the data will be a better solution.

Comment: @R Sahu, I still not understand why the GCC doesn't report error. Actually the executable also reference the static library. I dind't add the static library when link the executable and seams it just silent link to one of the copies in .so libraries. So the static library function is part of the interface of .so library, and gcc/linker should report error, am I correct?

Comment: @ZijingWu: It doesn't complain for the same reason that `library1.so` can define a symbol such as 'abc_123()` and `library2.so` can also define a symbol `abc_123()`, and there is no conflict (assuming that the link order is `-lrary1 -lrary2`).  If the code in `library2.so` calls `abc_123()`, you need to know whether it calls the version in `library1.so` or `library2.so`.  This is standard shared library stuff (indeed, standard library stuff; if the libraries were all static, then the first version of `abc_123()` would be used by everything).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Let me confirm. If `library1.so` define `abc_123()`, and `library2.so` also define `abc_123()`, and if I build the executable by `-lrary1 -lrary2`, and executable call `abc_123()`. Do you mean the function `library1.so::abc_123()` will be used silently, even the two `abc_123()` is different? So does there any standard document about that?

Comment: The main executable code, and the code from `library1.so` will definitely use the `abc_123()` from `library1.so`.  I'm not absolutely sure about whether the code in `library2.so` that calls `abc_123()` will end up using the version from `library1.so`, or whether it will end up using the version from `library2.so`.  (I'm assuming regular externally visible symbols; static functions etc are local to the library they're defined in, of course.)  I don't have documentation on the subject — though I'm sure it must exist.

Answer (score 3):

### Empirical evidence that shared library behaviour is platform-dependent

Here is some modest code that demonstrates two shared libraries both defining a symbol (function) `abc_123()` along with other functions calling the same function, and a test program that makes use these functions.

#### lib1.h

```
#ifndef JLSS_ID_LIB1_H
#define JLSS_ID_LIB1_H

extern void abc_123(int i);
extern void def_345(int i);

#endif
```

#### lib2.h

```
#ifndef JLSS_ID_LIB2_H
#define JLSS_ID_LIB2_H

extern void abc_123(int i);
extern void ghi_678(int i);

#endif
```

#### lib1a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib1.h"

void abc_123(int i)
{
    printf("Library 1:%s:%d:%s() - %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, i);
    printf("Note this extra message\n");
}
```

#### lib1b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"

void def_345(int i)
{
    printf("Library 1:%s:%d-->>%s() - %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, i);
    ghi_678(i+10);
    printf("Library 1:%s:%d<<--%s() - %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, i);
}
```

#### lib2a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib2.h"

void abc_123(int i)
{
    printf("Library 2:%s:%d:%s() - %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, i);
    printf("This is a completely different message\n");
}
```

#### lib2b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib2.h"

void ghi_678(int i)
{
    printf("Library 2:%s:%d-->>%s() - %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, i);
    abc_123(i * 10);
    printf("Library 2:%s:%d<<--%s() - %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, i);
}
```

#### test1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("Cross-library linking and calling\n");
    printf("Main calling abc_123(29)\n");
    abc_123(29);
    printf("Main calling def_345(45)\n");
    def_345(45);
    printf("Main calling ghi_678(57)\n");
    ghi_678(57);
    printf("Demonstration over\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### makefile

```
CC     = gcc #/usr/bin/gcc
WFLAG1 = -Wall
WFLAG2 = -Wextra
WFLAG3 = -Wmissing-prototypes
WFLAG4 = -Wstrict-prototypes
WFLAG5 = -Wold-style-definition
WFLAG6 = -Werror
WFLAGS = ${WFLAG1} ${WFLAG2} ${WFLAG3} ${WFLAG4} ${WFLAG5} ${WFLAG6}
SFLAGS = -std=c11
GFLAGS = -g
OFLAGS = -O3
UFLAGS = # Set on command line
IFLAG1 = # -I${HOME}/inc
IFLAGS = # ${IFLAG1}

SOEXT   = dylib
LDFLAG1 = -L.
LDLIB1  = -lrary1
LDLIB2  = -lrary2
LDFLAGS = ${LDFLAG1}
LDLIBS  = ${LDLIB1} ${LDLIB2}

CFLAGS  = ${OFLAGS} ${GFLAGS} ${IFLAGS} ${SFLAGS} ${WFLAGS} ${UFLAGS}

LNKSHLIB = -shared

LIBRARY1 = library1.${SOEXT}
LIBRARY2 = library2.${SOEXT}

LIB1.o  = lib1a.o lib1b.o
LIB2.o  = lib2a.o lib2b.o
TEST1.o = test1.o

PROGRAM = test1

all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${TEST1.o} ${LIBRARY1} ${LIBRARY2}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${TEST1.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

${LIBRARY1}: ${LIB1.o} ${LIBRARY2}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LNKSHLIB} -o $@ ${LIB1.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIB2}

${LIBRARY2}: ${LIB2.o}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LNKSHLIB} -o $@ ${LIB2.o}
```

### Build and run on Linux

This is from an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM (hosted on Mac OS X 10.9.3), and the compiler is GCC 4.8.2.

```
$ make -B SOEXT=so UFLAGS=-fPIC
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -c test1.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -c lib1a.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -c lib1b.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -c lib2a.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -c lib2b.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -shared -o library2.so lib2a.o lib2b.o
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -shared -o library1.so lib1a.o lib1b.o -L. -lrary2
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fPIC -o test1 test1.o -L. -lrary1 -lrary2
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./test1
Cross-library linking and calling
Main calling abc_123(29)
Library 1:lib1a.c:15:abc_123() - 29
Note this extra message
Main calling def_345(45)
Library 1:lib1b.c:17-->>def_345() - 45
Library 2:lib2b.c:15-->>ghi_678() - 55
Library 1:lib1a.c:15:abc_123() - 550
Note this extra message
Library 2:lib2b.c:17<<--ghi_678() - 55
Library 1:lib1b.c:19<<--def_345() - 45
Main calling ghi_678(57)
Library 2:lib2b.c:15-->>ghi_678() - 57
Library 1:lib1a.c:15:abc_123() - 570
Note this extra message
Library 2:lib2b.c:17<<--ghi_678() - 57
Demonstration over
$
```

Note that the `abc_123()` from `library1.so` is called each time, even when the calling function is `ghi_678()` from `library2.so`.

### Build and run on Mac OS X

This is from Mac OS X 10.9.3 with GCC 4.9.0.

```
$ make -B
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c -o test1.o test1.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c -o lib1a.o lib1a.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c -o lib1b.o lib1b.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c -o lib2a.o lib2a.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c -o lib2b.o lib2b.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -shared -o library2.dylib lib2a.o lib2b.o
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -shared -o library1.dylib lib1a.o lib1b.o -L. -lrary2
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -o test1 test1.o -L. -lrary1 -lrary2
$ ./test1
Cross-library linking and calling
Main calling abc_123(29)
Library 1:lib1a.c:15:abc_123() - 29
Note this extra message
Main calling def_345(45)
Library 1:lib1b.c:17-->>def_345() - 45
Library 2:lib2b.c:15-->>ghi_678() - 55
Library 2:lib2a.c:16:abc_123() - 550
This is a completely different message
Library 2:lib2b.c:17<<--ghi_678() - 55
Library 1:lib1b.c:19<<--def_345() - 45
Main calling ghi_678(57)
Library 2:lib2b.c:15-->>ghi_678() - 57
Library 2:lib2a.c:16:abc_123() - 570
This is a completely different message
Library 2:lib2b.c:17<<--ghi_678() - 57
Demonstration over
$
```

Note that the code in `ghi_678()` calls the `abc_123()` from `library2.so`, not the version from `library1.so` as on Linux.

You can play with the reverse linking order and see what happens then.

### Moral

Don't build software that contains the same function in multiple shared libraries; you will get confused if you port between platforms.

Comment: Good experiment. More sharing. Yes, actually I'm support Linux and Android, the android got break but Linux not when I move the code to an static library. I even thought it might by some macro which got the different behaviour for two platform. A big lesson. :)

Comment: Wy is this behavior so ?